# Can I transform MIDI to WAV without a library?

Tags: python, midi, pythonista

I am currently doing a PYTHON program and I want to transform midi to wav without a library NOR a program or website.
I found multiple posts telling me to download a library BUT I am coding in Pythonista (python IDE for iPhones and iPads) so since I am on mobile I can’t download those libs…

So if it’s possible could someone tell me how?

My code:

```
# modes: 1 = short classical songs, 2 = soundtrack games boss battle, 3 = sad music

mode = 2



from midiutil.MidiFile import MIDIFile
from random import randint as random
import sound
from time import sleep as wait


midi = MIDIFile(1, adjust_origin=True)

duration = 0

if mode == 1:
    duration = random(30, 200)
    midi.addTempo(0, 0, random(60, 360))
elif mode == 2:
    duration = random(660, 960)
    midi.addTempo(0, 0, random(360, 660))
elif mode == 3:
    duration = random(10,80)
    midi.addTempo(0, 0, random(30, 60))

for t in range(duration):
    pitch = random(60,80)
    midi.addNote(0, 0, pitch, t * 1 + random(0, 2), 1, 100)

with open('machine made song.txt', 'wb') as f:
    midi.writeFile(f)
    

player = sound.MIDIPlayer('machine made song.txt')
player.play()
```